# Scrolling background, JAVA

Tags: java, canvas, awt, thread-sleep

I need to make my background in a game move up all the time..

I know that I need to use some thread that added variable to 'y' coordinate of the image

I tried to do something but when it started moving all the background get streaking in some reason, cant understand why...

picture : [streaking background](http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=ewnlnnugwjzy.jpg)

```
public class Background {
private BufferedImage image;
.....
....

public Background(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    // Try to open the image file background.png
    try {
        BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
        image = loader.loadImage("/backSpace.png");

    }
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

}

/**
 * Method that draws the image onto the Graphics object passed
 * @param window
 */
public void draw(Graphics window) {

    // Draw the image onto the Graphics reference
    window.drawImage(image, getX(), getY(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);

    // Move the x position left for next time
    this.y +=1 ;
}


public class ScrollingBackground extends Canvas implements Runnable {

// Two copies of the background image to scroll
private Background backOne;
private Background backTwo;

private BufferedImage back;

public ScrollingBackground() {
    backOne = new Background();
    backTwo = new Background(backOne.getImageWidth(), 0);

    new Thread(this).start();
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(5);
            repaint();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}

@Override
public void update(Graphics window) {
    paint(window);
}

public void paint(Graphics window) {
    Graphics2D twoD = (Graphics2D)window;

    if (back == null)
        back = (BufferedImage)(createImage(getWidth(), getHeight()));

    Graphics buffer = back.createGraphics();

    backOne.draw(buffer);
    backTwo.draw(buffer);

    twoD.drawImage(back, null, 0, 0);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean be 'streaking'

Comment: I edit the question and add picture of the situation..

Comment: First of all you probably shouldn't be calling repaint(), its really meant to internal use. Secondly, the reason you are seeing streaking is because the graphics area is not being cleared is because calling repaint manually can prevent your canvas from being cleared. You should use update() instead.

Comment: Try calling the paint method directly?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a new thread for it, that just overcomplicates things in this case. 
You just need to add a factor to the Y coordinate of the background continuesly.
For example:

```
float scrollFactor = 0.5f; //Moves the background 0.5 pixels up per call of the draw method

public void draw(Graphics window) {

    window.drawImage(image, getX(), getY(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);

    this.y += scrollFactor;
}
```

Comment: So you tell me that my second class dont needed?

Comment: You don't need the second thread in your Background class, just call the paint method of your background class from your main game thread.

Comment: @user2922456 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Hmmm.. it should. Can you please add the getters to your question?

Comment: I dont need to load two pictuers into the buffer? The picture is over in some 'y'..not?

Comment: What do you mean with "I dont need to load two pictues into the buffer"?